# Bits required to encode difference between number of subgraphs with odd number of edges and number of subgraphs with even number of edges

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $H = ( V, E )$ be a $k$-uniform connected hypergraph, with $n = |V|$ vertices and $m = |E|$ hyperedges. Let $O_w$ be the number of edge induced subgraphs of $H$ having $w$ vertices and an odd number of hyperedges. Let $E_w$ be the number of edge induced subgraphs of $H$ having $w$ vertices and an even number of hyperedges. Let $\Delta_w = O_w - E_w$.

Let $b_w$ be the number of bits required to encode $\Delta_w$. Let $b = \displaystyle\max_{\substack{w}} b_w$.

I'm interested in how $b$ grows. I would like to determine the best possible upper bound for $b$ which is expressible as a function of only $n$, $m$ and $k$. More precisely, I would like to determine a function $f(n,m,k)$ having both the following properties:

1. $b \leq f( n, m, k )$ for any $k$-uniform hypergraph $H$ having $n$ vertices and $m$ hyperedges.
2. $f(n,m,k)$ grows slower than any other function which satisfies the 1<sup>st</sup> property.

In general both $O_w$ and $E_w$ are exponential in $m$, therefore I expect that their difference $\Delta_w$ is not exponential in $m$ and thus that $b \in o( m )$.

However for the moment I've no clue on how to try to prove this.

> **Questions**
>
> - How does $b$ grow with respect to $n$, $m$ and $k$?
> - Are there any relevant results in the literature?
> - Any hint on how to try to prove $b \in o(m)$?

---

**Update 13/09/2013**
Here are some clarifications:

- $O_w$ is the number of *distinct* edge-induced subgraphs in $H$. Repetitions are not allowed. The same holds for $E_w$ of course.
- By *"the number of bits required to encode $\Delta_w$"* I mean $log_2 \ \Delta_w$.

---

**Update 21/01/2016**
This question has been answered on [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/33609/947).

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by edge-induced?  Especially, will the subgraphs be connected and k-uniform for large w?

Comment: If the subgraphs are not k-uniform, looking at k-complete graphs should get b greater than 2n - logn.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Edge-InducedSubgraph.html

Comment: Of course every edge induced subgraph is $k$-uniform.

Comment: Even so, complete hypergraphs should set the bar pretty high for b.

Comment: By $k$-complete do you mean cliques of $k$ vertices? Could you please make your argument more clear?

Comment: Please note that we consider all edge induced subgraphs, including non-connected ones, therefore I do not see why _"complete hypergraphs should set the bar pretty high for $b$"_.